# Can bunny rabbits snore?

Tags: rabbits, sleep, snoring

My rabbit makes a squeaking sound when she sleeps.

Is this normal?

Can rabbits snore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes rabbits can snore.

The 7 exotic vets I've seen at "Angel Memorial" and 2 in my local rabbit rescue group "Sweet Binks" describe this as normal.

They often further generalize that rabbits with flatter faces like lop eared and some lion head breads have a genetic defect (which is why their face is flat) that leaves them with less developed sinuses which leave them prone to a plethora of respiratory issues that include snoring.

Comment: Asking and answering your own question is fine.  But when you do you should really try to give an answer that is comprehensive and includes references to any source material.  Why are you asking the question? What else can you tell us about these conditions that cause snoring?  Are there any signs that we should watch for that differentiates normal snoring from respiratory distress?

Comment: I noticed I had some less common knowledge about snoring being linked to flat faced rabbits, and felt this was the best way to present it.  I'm not sure if I can find a reference since the info came from my vet.

Comment: If the info came from your vet, then the part of the answer  "most vets will tell you it's normal" is not correct.  You really need references.